# how can one measure how many mysql joins bring best performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I am sending queries to a very large database (meaning many entities/tables).
So I have some queries which include some 7 to 8 joins. 
The problem is, that I do not know, how many entries the tables will have in near future. It could be between 1.000 to 100.000 rows each table (or even more).

I think about splitting my queries to perform two or three queries consecutively instead of one mega-query.

Is there a common/recommended limit of `JOIN`'s in an MySQL Query?
How can I measure/calculate which type of splitting would be a good variant (depending on count-of-rows in the tables, and so on)?

I have many `JOIN`'s on the same field (foreign-key) of the same table. Is there a way to optimize that as well? (one row in that table - has many relations/connections)

thanks ;)

**UPDATE:**

I saw it too late. Somebody was so nice and changed the title of the question.
Because of my bad English I wrote *performant* - meaning having good performance. I did't mean *to perform*!
Please consider this in your answers. thank again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to learn about EXPLAIN which will show you what MySQL's plan is for executing your query. e.g

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT foo FROM bar NATURAL JOIN baz
```

will tell you how MySQL would execute the query SELECT foo FROM bar NATURAL JOIN baz

From the EXPLAIN results you may see opportunities to add indexes to the database that will help your queries if they're slow, and in some cases, you may be able to add hints to the query e.g. telling MySQL to prefer one index over another if you have the experise to know that.

In general you will gain nothing from trying to "split up" a query unless your "splitting up" actually completely changes the semantics of what will need to be executed. e.g. if your query is fetching six unrelated things from the database, and you re-write this as six separate queries each fetching one thing, the aggregate time taken to execute will probably be no better (and may be much worse) for your separate queries.

Comment: I like your answer. I am looking for some kind of common rule. Do you know what I mean? (please consider my update)

Comment: So, you like my answer, but you've marked it as not accepted, and now you want a "common rule" instead? Can you give an example of what you imagine a "common rule" would look like?

Comment: what ever. I cannot put my thoughts into words - not in english and not in my language. so i just accept yours, because it helped me still.

Answer (score 1):

use 'desc (query);' to get a sense of how MySQL will treat your query. You are generally better off having MySQL do the joining and optimizing than doing it yourself. That's what its good at.

This will also tell you where indexing is working or needs to be augmented.